# xCode C++: no type named 'return_temporary_buffer' in namespace std

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, std

I'm trying to build a C++ OpenGL application in xCode 6.1.1 on OSX 10.9.5 for a Mac version of a game I'm writing. I've managed to achieve this before with prior versions of xCode (and presumably GCC) but I'm really struggling to get it to build.

I created the project as a Command Line Tool and added the required files and preprocessor macros to select the appropriate libraries but I'm getting compile errors with regards to standard libraries.

If I use libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library) I get errors in algorithm such as:

- Use of undeclared identifier of 'numeric_limits'
- No member named 'digits' in the global namespace
- No member named 'max' in the global namespace; did you mean simply 'max'?
- Use of undeclared identifier 'uint32_t'

If I use libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library) I get significantly less errors:

- stl_bvector.h: Use of undeclared identifier 'CHAR_BIT'
- stl_tempbuf.h:

  - No type named 'return_temporary_buffer' in namespace 'std' (x2)
  - No template named 'get_temporary_buffer'; did you mean '::std::_Temporary_buffer'?
  - Too few template arguments for class template '_Temporary_buffer'

So it seems the STD libraries have got screwed up but I don't understand how and if that is the case, why hasn't this been reported more? So I'm assuming I must be doing something wrong but I can't work out why...

Comment: The libc++ errors look like you're missing some headers, like <limits> and <cstdint>.

Comment: Makes sense but I would have thought that if something like <vector> and <string> (which are what I'm using) use the numeric limits etc. that they would have included it themselves. Or am I making a bad assumption?

Comment: You can't make any assumptions about which system headers are included by other system headers.

Comment: Fair enough. This is what I have now which has reduced some errors but still missing lot:

`#if MAC
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>
#endif
#include <vector>
#include <string>`

Also tried memory, iostream and stdlib but to no avail - its currently complaining about a lack of __destruct_n (which apparently should be in memory?).